# Logstash: How to link to a timestamp from a previous log message

Tags: filter, logstash, multiline, elastic-stack, grok

I am trying to create a grok pattern for something like this

```
********************************************************
18.03.13, 10:14:25: Starting new session 
********************************************************

 12:43:38   Warning: X-Ray blocked because signal  XRAY_ENABLE_FPD is high.
 13:31:08   Error 770.999 (DigitizerPt1000Pixium): 
OffsetCalibration: mode not active
 13:31:21   Error 770.999 (DigitizerPt1000Pixium): 
Cannot stop grabbing
```

However

```
13:31:08    Error 770.999 (DigitizerPt1000Pixium): 
OffsetCalibration: mode not active
```

this is a single log entry and not two(grok is considering it as two different entries)
Is there any pattern in grok or any other filter I can use???

Also I want to associate the date given in first line with warning and error log entries

Note:I have created grok pattern for it only following issues are unsolved.

I have tried using following code(for entire log file which is given here). But I am not able to link the date in first line with error and warning entries

```
input {
    file {
        path => "E:\Softwares\logstash-1.5.4\bin\Error_log_29092015.txt"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "E:/sincedb"
    }
}
filter {
    multiline {
       pattern => "^%{NOTSPACE}"
       what => previous

    }
        if "Starting" in [message]{
            grok {
                match => [ "message", "%{DATE_EU:Start_date}, %{TIME:Start_time}: %{WORD:session_status}"]          
                }
            }
        else if "Terminating" in [message] {
            grok{
              match => [ "message", "%{DATE_EU:Terminate_date}, %{TIME:Terminate_time}: %{WORD:session_status}"]
            }
        }

        else if "Warning" in [message] {
                                grok {
                                     match => [ "message", "%{TIME:Warning_time} \t%{WORD:Indicator}: %{GREEDYDATA:Warning_Message}\r"]     
                                    }

                            }
        else if "Error" in [message] { 
                        if "Generator" in [message]{
                            grok{
                            match => ["message","%{TIME:Error_time} \t%{WORD:Indicator} G %{NOTSPACE:Error_Num} %{NOTSPACE:Error_Type}: \r\n%{GREEDYDATA:Error_Message}\r"]
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                                grok {
                                     match => [ "message", "%{TIME:Error_time} \t%{WORD:Indicator} %{NOTSPACE:Error_Num} %{NOTSPACE:Error_Type}: \r\n%{GREEDYDATA:Error_Message}\r"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }   
        else if "Invalid" in [message]{
            grok {
                 match => [ "message", "%{TIME:InvalidCode_time} \t%{WORD:Type} Code. %{GREEDYDATA:InvalidCode_Message}"]
                }
            }   


        else if "Sedecal" in [message]{
            grok {
                 match => [ "message", "%{TIME:Sedecal_time} \t%{GREEDYDATA:Type}: %{GREEDYDATA:InvalidCode_Message}"]
                }
            }   
        else if "UIMS" in [message]{
            grok {
                 match => [ "message", "%{TIME:UIMSInternalState_time} \t%{GREEDYDATA:Type}: %{GREEDYDATA:UIMSInternalState_Message}"]
                }
            }       

        else {
            drop{}
        }                   

}

output {
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug}
    elasticsearch{
    cluster => "My_ProjectC"
        host => localhost
        codec => rubydebug} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiline plugin

```
input {
        stdin {
        }
}

filter{
        multiline{
                pattern => "^%{TIME}"
                negate => "true"
                what => "previous"
        }
}

output {
  stdout{codec => "rubydebug"}
}
```

All the logs which do not start with TIME will be merge to the previous log line.

After merge the multiline log, you can use grok to filter the field you want.

Comment: Thanks Ben, 

Appreciate your ans but there one problem in that as you can see on the first line there is 
18.03.13, 10:14:25: Starting new session 
and by your code this will also be shifted to previous line which I dont want 
If there is any other way ...


Also If there is any way i can add this date(18.03.13) to error and warning line

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not a merge, but the [*memorize* filter plugin for logstash](https://github.com/alcanzar/logstash-filter-memorize). It let's you remember date and time from a previous log message so that you can add it as a field later. There is already [a SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365239/logstash-use-of-memorize-plugin) showing its basic use.

The *memorize* plugin does not show up anymore in the [list of current filter plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) but [it should be still usable in logstash 2](https://github.com/alcanzar/logstash-filter-memorize/issues/2).