# Associating multiple fields with a single field with logstash

Tags: logstash

I am parsing some text files with logstash into elasticsearch where I am using the multiline filter to group multiple lines into the same document, and the grok filter to define regular expressions. However, the documents have a nested structure, so that some fields occur once while others occur several times in the same document. So for example, let's assume I have the following structure:

```
Family Name: Green
First Name: Mary, Age: 40, Length: 170 cm
First Name: Thomas, Age: 39, Length: 175 cm
First Name: John, Age: 10, Length: 110 cm
```

What I need to do is one of the following:

- Either to have one document for the family Green with 3 values each for first name, age and length
- Or to have 3 different documents where each contains the family name although it shows up in the text file only once.

Is it possible to implement any of the options (or both of them) using logstash?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [memorize](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-filter-memorize/) plugin that will do what you want.  There is an example of using it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26366323/2785358).

If you are using logstash 5.0, use a command like this to install the plugin:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-memorize
```

If you are using prior to 5.0, use a command like this:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install --version 0.9.2 logstash-filter-memorize
```